# Static Cell properties having no effect when set in storyboard IB

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, static

I have dragged a table view into my view, set it to static, set the number of cells and sections, changed colours, added controls and modified the size. When I run it though, the changes do not show up. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is your view controller (or the object that is the table views delegate and datasource) a subclass of? And have you actually connected these outlets (you still have to, even with static tables)

Comment: I had it all set up and connected, but I still got this error. I Fixed it by just using a TableViewController preset.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means but if you've fixed it, post an answer!